# Why iconv cannot convert emoji utf-8-mac to utf8

Tags: macos, utf-8, emoji, iconv, unicode-normalization

I am trying to push some files from my system to a linux machine with rsync from a mac.  Since I downloaded these files automatically from the internet, they sometimes have odd(stupid) filenames.

Take this gem for example:

```
rsync --iconv=utf-8-mac,utf-8 -av $PWD/ pi@raspberrypi.local:/media/dest
[sender] cannot convert filename: .jpg (Illegal byte sequence)
```

It looks like iconv can't handle that particular name for some reason, which is odd since my understanding is this just makes rsync convert unicode NFD to NFC.  Is this a bug in iconv, or is this happening for some other reason because of some quirk of encoding I don't understand?

I would assume emoji have equivalent composed and decomposed form, since there is no way you could add some form of combining diacritic to an emoji.

Comment: Please add rsync versions on local and remote, and the protocol that was agreed upon

Comment: sender=3.1.2 protocol 31; receiver  3.0.9  protocol 30, so I guess the next step is upgrade the receiver then.  But OS reports nothing to upgrade.

Comment: These versions should be OK, I just wanted to make sure you have 3.x on both sides.

Comment: Ok i guess you can composite emoji, but it still seems broken https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%F0%9F%91%A9%E2%80%8D%F0%9F%91%A9%E2%80%8D%F0%9F%91%A7%E2%80%8D%F0%9F%91%A6